# Why JSON stores object like this {"city":[{"com.getcity.@FAE87A"}]}

Tags: java, json, jdbc, arraylist, pojo

```
String getCity = request.getParameter("name1");
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
try {
    ConnectToDb db = new ConnectToDb();

    con =db.getConnect();
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select Name, CountryCode, District, Population from city where name =?");
    pstmt.setString(1, getCity);
    rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<getCity> getinfo = new ArrayList<getCity>();

    while(rs.next()){
        getCity gc = new getCity();
        gc.setCity(rs.getString("name"));
        gc.setContryCode(rs.getString("CountryCode"));
        gc.setDistrict(rs.getString("district"));
        gc.setPopulation(rs.getString("population"));
        getinfo.add(gc);
    }

    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    jobj.put("city", getinfo);
    System.out.println(jobj);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

output :

```
{"city":[{"city":"Perm","district":"Perm","contryCode":"RUS","population":"1009700"}]}
```

But same code when I execute in other machine output gets something like this: `{"city":[{"com.getCity.@AF345E"}]}`.

Why does this is happen?

Comment: Looks like the part which is supposed to return the city part is failing and returning the url maybe it gets it from?

Answer (score 2):

```
com.getCity.@AF345E
```

It is an "getCity" object without implementing "toString" method. Check your code.

Comment: But in other machine output is proper and in other it is showing object why this is ?